# Why does xrdp service fail to start?

Tags: xrdp

xrdp service fails to start:

```
john@Demonstrator:~$ systemctl status xrdp.service
```

× xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: >
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-08-15 08:44:54 BST; 28s >
Docs: man:xrdp(8)
man:xrdp.ini(5)
Process: 186632 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited>
Process: 186640 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status>
CPU: 15ms

Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(7, 3389) failed b>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon,>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, >
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
...skipping...
× xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: >
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-08-15 08:44:54 BST; 28s >
Docs: man:xrdp(8)
man:xrdp.ini(5)
Process: 186632 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited>
Process: 186640 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status>
CPU: 15ms

Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(7, 3389) failed b>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator xrdp[186640]: [ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon,>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, >
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit>
Aug 15 08:44:54 Demonstrator systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.

Comment: Used the webpage at https://orcacore.com/install-configure-xrdp-ubuntu-22-04/. xrdp got further but it fails with:
Aug 23 12:25:56 Demonstrator systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Aug 23 12:25:56 Demonstrator xrdp[1334835]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Aug 23 12:25:56 Demonstrator xrdp[1334835]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Aug 23 12:25:56 Demonstrator xrdp[1334835]: [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(7, 3389) failed bind

Comment: hello there....looks like something is already using port 3389 on your system. by default xrdp would use port 3389.  have you enabled gnome remote desktop on your system ?  The other problem might be also that the xrdp-sesman process is also failing... Please double check if port 3389 is in used by other process or not